# typescript type array argument extending generic class

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic interface:

```
export interface A<T> {
}
```

then I also have another generic interface (this is what I need help with):

```
export interface B<T> {
  aTypes: Type[] extends A<T>[];
}
```

what I want to be able to do is that when I create a class extending B it has a type array which extends type A like this:

```
export class AClass implements A<string> {

}

export class BClass implements B<string> {
  aTypes: [
  AClass
];
}
```

Comment: How does this depend on angular?

Comment: In order for this to be a [mre] you need more details in the code. [Empty classes](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) and [unused generic type parameters](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--) have strange and confusing side effects that only distract from your issue. Also, it's not clear what you're doing with `aTypes`, could you show an example use? I want to understand whether it should be holding *instances* or *constructors* of `A`. Please [edit] to fix these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but this is probably what you are looking for:

```
export interface A<T> {}

export interface B<T, U extends A<T>> {
  aTypes: U[];
}

export class AClass implements A<string> {}

export class BClass implements B<string, AClass> {
  aTypes: [
    AClass
  ];
}
```